Unable to Install Python 3.6.8 Using PyEnv in an Ubuntu Docker Container: Segmentation Fault and Missing libffi
I'm attempting to set up a new Docker container using the Ubuntu latest image and install multiple Python versions using PyEnv. While I successfully installed Python 3.8.10, I'm encountering issues when trying to install Python 3.6.8.
Steps to Reproduce:

Start the Docker container:
docker run -it --label 'python-envs' -v ~/Desktop/python-envs/:/workspace/python-envs:rw --hostname python --name python-envs ubuntu:latest

System information with uname -a:
Linux python 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Installed pyenv: curl https://pyenv.run | bash

Verify installed Python versions, I installed version 3.8.10 before and had success:
pyenv versions
Output:
* system (set by /root/.pyenv/version)
3.8.10

installed the needed libraries:

apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev

Attempt to install Python 3.6.8:

pyenv install 3.6.8
Error Encountered:
Downloading Python-3.6.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.8...
/root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 1863: 30193 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$PYTHON_BIN" -c "import $1"
WARNING: The Python ctypes extension was not compiled. Missing the libffi lib?
/root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 2089: 30200 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$PYTHON_BIN" $python_opts -m ensurepip ${ensurepip_opts} > /dev/null 2>&1
Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py...
/root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 2065: 30204 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "${PYTHON_BIN}" -s "${get_pip}" ${GET_PIP_OPTS} 1>&4 2>&1
error: failed to install pip via get-pip.py

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 24.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20240612063012.18758
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20240612063012.18758.log

Last 10 log lines:
                install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
        esac; \
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20240612063012.18758/Python-3.6.8 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
                $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpm_fdsrq7
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-18.1 setuptools-40.6.2

Cleaned up previous attempts: pyenv uninstall 3.6.8
Used environment variables to adjust build configuration:
CFLAGS="-O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt \
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC" \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed" \

None of these steps have resolved the issue. What could be causing the segmentation fault during the installation of Python 3.6.8 using PyEnv? Are there additional steps or configurations I need to consider?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Do you have an excellent reason to try to install a version of Python that hasn't had security support for 2.5 years? (It's entirely possible it simply isn't compatible with Ubuntu 24.04.)

Anyway, you should be able to use your usual debugging tools (e.g. gdb) to figure out why the Python in /tmp/python-build.20240612063012.18758 (or whatever is your build tree) is segfaulting.

@AKX The environment I'm working in requires special treatments for some of the internal apps. If it is not compatible with Ubuntu 24.03 which version should I use?

I'd try 20.04, it still has 5 years of lifetime to it.

@AKX Got it, will try that version of Ubuntu.
